# Wind speed measuring using Hall effect Anemometer

Tags: arduino-uno, hall-effect

I need your help regarding a problem I am facing while measuring wind speed. In my sketch I get a reading every 20 counts which the magnet goes past the sensor. I need to change it in order to get a reading every 20 seconds. How can I do it with minimum changes to the sketch?

```
volatile byte revolutions;

float rpmilli;
float speed;


unsigned long timeold=0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), rpm_fun, RISING);

  revolutions = 0;
  rpmilli = 0;
  timeold = 0;
}

void loop()
{
  if (revolutions >= 20) { 
    //Update RPM every 20 counts, increase this for better RPM resolution,
    //decrease for faster update

    // calculate the revolutions per milli(second)
    rpmilli = ((float)revolutions)/(millis()-timeold);

    timeold = millis();
    revolutions = 0;

    // WHEELCIRC = 2 * PI * radius (in meters)
    // speed = rpmilli * WHEELCIRC * "milliseconds per hour" / "meters per kilometer"

    // simplify the equation to reduce the number of floating point operations
    // speed = rpmilli * WHEELCIRC * 3600000 / 1000
    // speed = rpmilli * WHEELCIRC * 3600

    speed = rpmilli * 0.6597 * 3600;

    Serial.print("RPM:");
    Serial.print(rpmilli * 60000);
    Serial.print(" Speed:");
    Serial.print(speed);
    Serial.println(" kph");
  }
}

void rpm_fun()
{
  revolutions++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `millis()` function to measure time intervals and do things regularly in these intervals. Refer to the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example, that comes with the Arduino IDE, or to one of the many tutorials for the `millis()` function on the web.

Basically you will need to do the following:

1. Declare a timestamp variable to hold the time when the data was displayed last time (in global scope):

   ```
    unsigned long timestamp = 0;
   ```
2. Declare the interval, that you want the display to happen in:

   ```
    #define DISPLAY_INTERVAL  20000
   ```
3. In your if statement check if the time difference between now and the timestamp is bigger than the interval

   ```
    if(millis() - timestamp > DISPLAY_INTERVAL){
   ```

   Note that you should do `millis()` comparisons always this way (by calculating the difference), so that the rollover of `millis()` will not affect the result.